# How to ignore lines starting with a string with diff?

Tags: unix, diff

How can I diff two files and ignore lines starting with a sequence.

E.g

```
File1:
abc
def
time:123

File2:
igh
def
time:345
```

With unix diff it will report

```
<time:123
>time:345
```

I want to ignore this diff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about: `diff -I '^time.*' file1 file2`?

Please note it [doesn't always work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807135/55075) as per [`diffutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Specified-Lines.html#Specified-Lines) manual:

> However, `-I` only ignores the insertion or deletion of lines that contain the regular expression if every changed line in the hunk (every insertion and every deletion) matches the regular expression.
>
> In other words, for each non-ignorable change, `diff` prints the complete set of changes in its vicinity, including the ignorable ones. You can specify more than one regular expression for lines to ignore by using more than one `-I` option. `diff` tries to match each line against each regular expression, starting with the last one given.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
diff <(grep -v '^time:' file1) <(grep -v '^time:' file2)
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the -q option, I guess, but otherwise it's good.

Comment: Such a trick, I dont know why we have to work this way, but we have to. Thank you