# ignore pattern with backward slash in diff command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, diff, backslash

File foo.c:

```
do {                                                            
    a=b;
    c=d;
 } while (0)
```

File bar.c

```
do {                                                            
    a=b;
    c=d;
\
} while (0)
```

In shell script the diff of above 2 files:

> diff foo.c bar.c

```
<   } while (0)
---
>     \
>   } while (0)
```

I am trying to ignore this diff using

> **diff -I "reg-ex pattern"**.

I tried pattern like `"\s}\swhile\s(0)"`  , `"} while (0)"` etc. But no use. Is it possible to ignore the above case? If not "diff", any other utility?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by deleting the unwanted lines with sed. And then ignoring the differences.

You have 2 differences between foo.c and bar.c

1. Line with `\`
2. There is a space before `}` in foo.c

You can do something like this:

```
diff -I '\s\?}' <(sed '/^\\/d' bar.c) foo.c
```

Delete the line with `\` using sed and ignore the space in foo.c

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pat='^[[:space:]]*\\[[:space:]]*$'
sub_pat='s/'"$pat"'//'
diff -B -I "$pat" <(sed -e "$sub_pat" foo.c) <(sed -e "$sub_pat" bar.c)
```

The first line stores a regular expression into `pat` variable for the next `diff` and `sed` commands. The regular expression matches a line with a backslash (`\\`) optionally surrounded with space characters.

The `sed` commands replace the lines matching `$pat` pattern with empty strings (`-B` option causes `diff` to ignore blank lines).

---

It is impossible to filter out the backslashes from the output of `diff` without extra tools, unless the only difference is in the lines containing the pattern being ignored:

> for each nonignorable change, `diff' prints the complete set of changes in its vicinity, including the ignorable ones.

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807135/why-diff-with-ignore-matching-lines-doesnt-work-as-expected) for details.