# When comparing directories with diff is there a way to exclude certain file differences from the output?

Tags: linux, unix, diff

I am running this command:

```
diff --recursive a.git b.git
```

It shows differences for some files that do not concern me. Is there a way to for example not have it show lines that end in:

```
 ".xaml.g.cs"
```

or lines that start in:

```
 "Binary files"
```

or lines that have this text in them:

```
".git/objects"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple but effective way is to pipe output to `grep`. With `grep -Ev` you can ignore lines using regular expressions.

```
diff --recursive a.git b.git | grep -Ev "^< .xaml.g.cs|^> .xaml.g.cs"  | grep -Ev "Binary files$" | grep -v ".git/objects"
```

This ignores all lines with matching text. As for the regular expressions: `^` means line starts with, `$` means line ends with. But at least for `^` you have to adjust it to the `diff` output (where lines normally start with `<` or `>`).

Also note that `diff` provides a flag `--ignore-matching-lines=RE` but it might not work as you would expect as [mentioned in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807135/why-diff-with-ignore-matching-lines-doesnt-work-as-expected). And because it does not work as I would expect I rather use `grep` for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

```
man diff
```

gives following examples:

```
   ...
   -x, --exclude=PAT
          exclude files that match PAT

   -X, --exclude-from=FILE
          exclude files that match any pattern in FILE
   ...
```

Did you try using those switches (like `diff -x=".xaml.g.cs" --recursive a.git b.git`)?